# Parallel trend assumption in difference-in-differences

Tags: mean, median, trend, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I want to run a difference in difference model to evaluate the impact of a policy change using panel data with 30 individuals in the control group and 35 individuals in the treatment group.

When investigating the trends of the dependent variable for the two groups before the policy change, the dynamics of the ***means*** for the two groups are not parallel (upper panel in the figure below). However, when looking at the ***medians*** of the dependent variable for the two groups across time before the policy change, there seems to be a common trend (lower panel in the figure below).

The problem is that the distribution of the dependent variable is skewed right, and given the low number of individuals, the mean is very sensitive to extreme values.

1. What are the possible solutions in this case?
2. Are the parallel trends observed for the median enough to run somekind of a quantile difference-in-differences? I would welcome any reference.
3. Are there any other alternatives?
   [image]

Comment: Please let me know if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: You could have a look at Athey and Imbens (2006), who propose a generalised DiD method looking at the quantiles of the outcome. https://www.jstor.org/stable/3598807

Comment: hi, @user6441253, did you figure out?

Comment: Hi, yes. Athey and Imbens (2006) offers two types of model to study quantiles: the change-in-change model and the quantile DID.